# How to Style these kind of buttons in css?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone please help in styling these kind of buttons?

[image]

Comment: you can use -webkit-transform: skew(20deg), try this

Comment: Look for skew on this page https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Comment: Thanks Guys for quick response

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_skew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The skew css property has already been mentioned here and it's all great stuff and there is good answers. But just to make an alternative where the text is not skewed you can place an element like a `<div>` inside the button and counter the skew of the button so the text is straight.

```css
button {
  border:0;
  background:red;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  padding:15px 30px;
  transform:skewX(-20deg);
}

button div {
  transform:skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div>Pay now</div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **skew** css property

```css
button{border:0;background:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;
transform:skewX(-20deg);}
button div{transform:skewX(20deg);}
```

```html
Text also skewed:
<button>Pay now</button>

<br><!--br tag just for spacing purpose not recommended-->
<br><!--br tag just for spacing purpose not recommended-->

Text without skewed:
<button><div>Pay now</div></button>
```

About skew ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp))

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without skew the text:

```css
.button {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 25px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 25px 10px 0 0;
  border-color: red transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">PAY NOW</button>
```

It can't be used if the button is an `input` because doesn't support `::after` and `::before`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the skew in css as below

```
<div>
   <button class="button">PAY NOW</button>
</div>

.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: skew(150deg)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.karenmenezes.com/2014/jun/18/slanted-buttons-3-lines-css/

http://codepen.io/peterhry/pen/pxrkK/

Try these buttons links:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px/1.4;
  margin: 5em;
  background: #667;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  border: .125em solid #000;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font: 1.5em/1.4 'Oswald', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;        
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(.5em 1em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -moz-filter:  drop-shadow(.5em 1em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -o-filter:  drop-shadow(.5em 1em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -ms-filter:  drop-shadow(.5em 1em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  filter: url(#f1); 
  filter:  drop-shadow(.5em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  margin-right: 3em;
}

.btn:active {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(.25em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -moz-filter:  drop-shadow(.25em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -o-filter:  drop-shadow(.25em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -ms-filter:  drop-shadow(.25em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  filter: url(#f2); 
  filter:  drop-shadow(.25em .5em .25em rgba(0,0,0,.4));
  -webkit-transform: translate(.25em, .5em);
  -moz-transform: translate(.25em, .5em);
  transform: translate(.25em, .5em);
}

.btn.double:before,
.btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #333;
  border: .125em solid #000;
  width: 1.125em;
  height: 100%;
  top: -.125em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
  -moz-transform-origin: bottom left;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.btn:after {
  right: -.25em;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  border-left: none;
}

.btn.double:before {
  left: -.25em;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(20deg);
  -moz-transform: skewX(20deg);
  transform: skewX(20deg);
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="btn"></div>
</body>
```